# C# array indexing

Tags: java, c#, arrays

Apology in advance if this is an obvious question.

I just switched from java to C# and I am doing practice in C# in order to get myself familiar with it. 
It's just a binary search program.

1. there is an error in this line `key > array[mid]`
   cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type system.array.
2. I tried to google it and someone said it should be `key > array.GetValue(mid)`,but after changing it the error becomes "Operator < cannot be applied to operands of type int and object".

I really don't know what to do and I don't have anybody to discuss it, so any help or any advice about switching from java to C# would be great. Thanks.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace BinarySearch.BinarySearch
{
    class BinarySearch
    {
        public int BinarySearch(int key, Array array)
        {
            int lowerbound = 0, upperbound = array.Length, mid = 0, count = 0, midValue = 0;

            while (lowerbound <= upperbound)
            {
                mid = (lowerbound + upperbound)>>1;

                if (key < array[mid])
                {
                    upperbound = mid - 1;
                    count++;
                }
                else if (key > array[mid])
                {
                    lowerbound = mid + 1;
                    count++;
                }
                else
                {
                    count++;
                    return mid;
                }
            }

            return -1;   //the key does not exist in this array.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `Array array` should be `int[] array`

Comment: That's right, thank you ^_^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really want to use the type `Array` in your code, you can use the `GetValue()` method, but you need to cast the returned `object` instance back to `int` to compare it. E.g.:

```
if (key < (int)array.GetValue(mid))
```

But that's probably not what you actually want. You should be using the array the same way you use it in Java. E.g.:

```
public int BinarySearch(int key, int[] array)
```

then you can write expression exactly as you would in Java:

```
if (key < array[mid])
```

Finally, a couple of other things:

1. Your code returns an `Array`, which doesn't make any sense. I changed the return type in the above example to `int`
2. .NET already has a perfectly good [binary search implementation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.binarysearch(v=vs.110).aspx). One hopes this is just for your own edification, rather than something used in production code somewhere. :)

Comment: Thanks a lot! But in what kind of situation should I use the GetValue mathod? It seems doing the same thing as indexing?

Comment: You don't, in general, use the `GetValue()` method. Arrays have special support in C# and every other .NET language I'm aware of, and so you can use each language's built-in array syntax. You would only need to use `GetValue()` in a scenario where you're either using a (hypothetical) language that doesn't support arrays directly, or you need to deal with arrays in a non-type-safe manner (i.e. you don't have knowledge of the actual element type of the array). These scenarios rarely occur.